# How to run a BigQuery Script by Google App Scripts after a table is updated by another BigQuery script?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have developed a quite code heavy and data heavy query for Google BigQuery which is why I have chosen to run it in multiple scripts (and create multiple tables). What I want is to run script b (and create table b) when tabel a is updated (by script a). I see only the option to set time events and I'm not that experienced with javascripting. Can someone provide an example?

Thanks in advance!

Guido

```
  function saveQueryToTable() {
var sql = 'query-a';
var projectId = 'xxx';
var datasetId = 'xxx';
var tableId = 'xxx';
var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: sql,
        writeDisposition:'WRITE_APPEND',
        allowLargeResults: 'TRUE',
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        }       
      }
    }
  };

var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
  Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}

  function saveQueryToTable() {
var sql = 'query-b';
var projectId = 'xxx';
var datasetId = 'xxx';
var tableId = 'xxx';
var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: sql,
        writeDisposition:'WRITE_APPEND',
        allowLargeResults: 'TRUE',
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        }       
      }
    }
  };

var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
  Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just start query A, wait for it and then start query B? GBQ API has appropriate endpoints which allows that.

Comment: @MarcinPietraszek That would be perfect. I have added the app script in my question. Can you maybe give an example about what I need to modify?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults

@MarcinPietraszek I found this documentation of the API. I think I need to evaluate if the jobComplete of script a is true before firing script b, but I dont know how to write this into code. Would really appreciate if you can help!

Comment: I guess I need a second function to evaluate the Jobcomplete of the job that fired query a, but I really suck at javascript :(

Comment: Yes, you need to write another thingy that's going to check status of particular job. When it's DONE and there are no errors you could start next one.

Comment: @MarcinPietraszek Thanks for the reply. Could you maybe provide an example based on the code in the question?